# linux find all files where directory or filename contains a text

Tags: linux, find

I want to find files where a given text is present either in file name or in path.

for eg:
`find /a/b/ -name "*log*" -type f -or -name "*log*" -type d`

(**EDIT:**
Looks like `find /a/b/ -name "*log*"`  will give same result as above.)

The above commands will give all directory or files with `log` in it. the result will be like this.

```
/a/b/log      -directory
/a/b/c/log.txt     -file
/a/b/log/log.txt   -file
/a/b/log/xx.txt    -file
```

But I want only below results with filename, where log is present anywhere in the path(Want to omit the first line in the above result, to be precise)

```
/a/b/c/log.txt    
/a/b/log/log.txt
/a/b/log/xx.txt
```

Is it possible to limit to only files in result but both files and directories in search condition?

Comment: Why is `/a/b/log` exclude from your desired result?

Comment: @RedCricket because it is a directory. I wanted only files

Comment: What result is your current command producing?

Comment: Not clear why you must include `-or -name "*log*" -type d `, If  you remove that, you'll have the result you're asking for. But not really a programming question and more appropriate to [su] or possibly [unix.se]. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: @shellter if `type d` is omitted then `*log*` will be searched in file name only right?

Comment: Yes, and your desired results show that.

Comment: @shellter. But i am not getting `/a/b/log/xx.txt` in the desired result , if i remove `type d`

Comment: @RedCricket modifed the question to show the current result. Sorry if my question is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted :

```
find /a/b -type f -path "*log*"
```

Comment: Yes.  exactly this what I was looking for. Thank you..